# Rails API GET function without view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api

I'm building a rails app that is very api heavy. I would like to be able to call a function that requests API data. I want to be able to call this function from any controller, which will run a function and update the User model.

How would I do this? in terms of where do I write it and how to I access it?

thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you mean by API. You mean a Controller action, that will be accessed by multiple Rails views, and will update the User model?

Comment: I want a controller action that doesn't have a view. I.e. I would like to update my user data from another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As every Controller inherit's from ApplicationConttroller by default, every method/function defined there will be visible from any Controller.

But if you want to access it from outside of the ApplicationController scope (views, helpers etc.) you will need to create an action. You can set what this action will render by using the 'render' method and it's options (more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)).

Example:

```
    render :nothing => true
```

Or if you need that action to return some kind of data, you could use 'json':

```
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: data, status: :ok }
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an action without a view like this:

```
def action
  data = params #Do your work here 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: data, status: :ok }
  end
end
```

Create the route in config/routes.rb:

```
get '/controller/action', to: 'controller#action'
```

Comment: Everything makes sense until you config/routes.rb Is that what you meant to write? Repeats itself